# Probability Problem... Stuck in Venn diagram

Tags: probability

Given $P(B)=\frac{3}{4}$, $P(A\cap B\cap \bar C)=\frac{1}{3}$, and $P(\bar A\cap B\cap \bar C)=\frac{1}{3}$, find $P(B\cap C)$. The answer choices are

(a) $\frac{1}{12}$, (b) $\frac{1}{9}$, (c)$\frac{1}{15}$ and (d)$\frac{1}{18}$

Ans: option a)

I tried using Venn diagram but my answer is not matching with any options

Comment: you should really type out the problem statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw a generic Venn Diagram.  We will start inserting numbers.

Work first with $A\cap B\cap\bar{C}$.  Can you identify this little region? It is the stuff that is in $A$, in $B$, but outside $C$. Write $1/3$ in that region.

Work next with $\bar{A}\cap B\cap \bar{C}$. This is the region outside $A$ and $C$, but inside $B$. Write $1/3$ in that region.

These two regions make up **part** of $B$. Since $B$ has probability $\dfrac{3}{4}$, the **rest** of $B$  has probability $\dfrac{3}{4}-\dfrac{1}{3}-\dfrac{1}{3}$, which simplifies to $\dfrac{1}{12}$.

But this "rest of $B$" is just $B\cap C$.

**Remark:** The tricky thing about this problem is that we are not given enough information to fill in *all* the probabilities in the Venn diagram. But we *are* given enough information to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

The facts you have allow you to find $P(B\cap \overline C)$. Now use that $P(B\cap C)+P(B\cap\overline C)=\frac 34$.